# My scroll-snap issue, not scroll snapping in y or x in tailwind-css

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, react-component

So I am using tailwind in react. And I am trying to do scroll snap x and y. When I try scroll snap x, it slides on the x-axis but does not snap. When I try scroll snap y, it shrinks all of my divs in the container component. So my problem is that scroll snap x and y are not working. Can you please fix both of them? Ask me any questions about my question and I will answer. Here is my code(The code is set to scroll snap y, but I need help on both scroll snap x and scroll snap y):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Get Information Before Comps Start" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Education, Study" />
    <meta name="author" content="Srimaan, Nahom" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body id="bodyWithId">
    <script type="text/babel">
      function ItemOne() {
        return (
          <div className="snap-start bg-blue-200 grid w-screen h-screen place-items-center text-8xl">
            1
          </div>
        );
      }

      function ItemTwo() {
        return (
          <div className="snap-start bg-orange-200 grid w-screen h-screen place-items-center text-8xl">
            2
          </div>
        );
      }

      function ItemThree() {
        return (
          <div className="snap-start bg-green-200 grid w-screen h-screen place-items-center text-8xl">
            3
          </div>
        );
      }

      function Container() {
        return <div className="flex snap-y h-screen w-full mx:auto overflow-scroll">
          <ItemOne />
          <ItemTwo />
          <ItemThree />
        </div>;
      }

      ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById("bodyWithId"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To scroll down/up your code should work, but for scroll left/right you need replace `w-screen` to `min-w-full` to push all items out of the screen and leave only one.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="snap-y snap-mandatory h-screen w-screen mx:auto overflow-x-hidden">
  <div class="snap-start bg-blue-200 grid w-screen h-screen place-items-center text-8xl">1</div>
  <div class="snap-start bg-orange-200 grid w-screen h-screen place-items-center text-8xl">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="snap-start bg-green-200 grid w-screen h-screen place-items-center text-8xl">
    3
  </div>

  <!-- scroll to right -->
  <div class="snap-start snap-x flex snap-mandatory h-screen w-screen mx:auto overflow-y-hidden">
    <div class="snap-start bg-blue-200 grid min-w-full h-screen place-items-center text-8xl">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="snap-start bg-orange-200 grid min-w-full h-screen place-items-center text-8xl">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="snap-start bg-green-200 grid min-w-full h-screen place-items-center text-8xl">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following class "touch-pan-x", it's working for me and style the scrollbar

```html
<div className="flex flex-row gap-6 mb-8 snap-x overflow-x-scroll snap-mandatory touch-pan-x w-full h-full"> 
...
</div>
```